# Angular - core.js:6456 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined in null image upload

Tags: angular

In Angular-12, I am trying to insert profile with image. But the image is optional.

Component:

```js
formData.append("company_logo", this.files, this.files.name);

imageSrcLogo!: string | ArrayBuffer;
path = "";
files ? : any;
companySetupForm!: FormGroup;
companyInfoForm!: FormGroup;


createCompany() {
  this.companyInfoForm = this.fb.group({
    companyName: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(3), Validators.maxLength(100)]],
    company_logo: ['', [
      RxwebValidators.extension({
        extensions: ["jpg", "jpeg", "bmp", "png", "gif", "svg"]
      })
    ]]
  });
}

onSelectFile(event: any) {
  if (event.target.files && event.target.files[0]) {
    var reader = new FileReader();

    reader.readAsDataURL(event.target.files[0]); // read file as data url
    this.files = event.target.files[0];
    reader.onload = (event: any) => { // called once readAsDataURL is completed
      //   console.log(event);
      this.url = event.target.result;
    }
  }
}


onSubmit() {
  this.isSubmitted = true;

  // stop here if form is invalid
  if (this.companyInfoForm.invalid) {
    return;
  }

  const formCompanyData = this.companyInfoForm.getRawValue();

  const formData = new FormData();

  formData.append('companyName', formCompanyData.companyName);
  formData.append("company_logo", this.files, this.files.name);

  this.spinnerService.show();
  const header = {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
  };

  this.isLoading = true;

  this.companySignupService.uploadData(formData).subscribe(res => {
      this.data = res;
      this.tokenHandler(res);
    },
    error => {
      this.store.dispatch(loadErrorMessagesSuccess(error));
      this.isLoading = false;
    });
  this.isLoading = false;
}

tokenHandler(data: any) {
  Swal.fire({
    position: 'center',
    icon: 'success',
    title: data.message,
    showConfirmButton: true,
    timer: 5000
  });
  this.router.navigateByUrl('/auth');
}

onFileChange(event: any) {
  this.files = event.target.files[0];
}
```

HTML:

```html
<form [formGroup]="companyInfoForm">
  <ng-template matStepLabel matStepperIcon="phone">Company Info</ng-template>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3">
      <div class="card card-primary card-outline">
        <div class="card-body box-profile">
          <div class="text-center">
            <img class="profile-user-img img-fluid img-circle" [src]="url || 'assets/img/no-image.png'" alt="No Company Logo" onerror="this.src='assets/img/no-image.png'" style="height:150px; width:150px">
          </div>

          <h3 class="profile-username text-center">Company Logo</h3>

          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="company_logo"></label>
            <input formControlName="company_logo" id="company_logo" type="file" class="form-control" accept=".jpg,.jpeg,.bmp,.png,.gif,.svg" (change)="onSelectFile($event)">
            <div *ngIf="fc.company_logo.touched && fc.company_logo.invalid">
              <div *ngIf="fc.company_logo.hasError('extension')">
                <div class="text-danger">
                  Enter valid File Type!
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-9">
      <div class="card-body">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-12 col-md-6">
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="name">Company Name:<span style="color:red;">*</span></label>
              <input type="text" formControlName="companyName" placeholder="Company Name" class="form-control" required/>
            </div>
            <div *ngIf="fc.companyName.touched && fc.companyName.invalid">
              <div *ngIf="fc.companyName.hasError('required')">
                <div class="text-danger">
                  Company Name is required!
                </div>
              </div>
              <div *ngIf="fc.companyName.hasError('minlength')">
                <div class="text-danger">
                  Company Name cannot be less than 3 characters!
                </div>
              </div>
              <div *ngIf="fc.companyName.hasError('maxlength')">
                <div class="text-danger">
                  Company Name cannot be more than 100 characters!
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="card-footer">
      <button mat-raised-button color="primary" matStepperNext (click)="companyNext()">Next</button>
    </div>
</form>

<button mat-raised-button color="success" [disabled]="isLoading" type="submit" (click)="onSubmit()">
                <span *ngIf="isLoading" class="spinner-border spinner-border-sm mr-1"></span>
                  Submit
              </button>
```

Basically, the imaage (company_logo) is optional. If user submits with image upload, no error is generated, and everything is inserted.

But if user submits without image upload, this error is generated:

```
core.js:6456 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined
 at SignupCompanyComponent.onSubmit (signup-company.component.ts:247)
 at SignupCompanyComponent_Template_button_click_212_listener (signup-company.component.html:404)
 at executeListenerWithErrorHandling (core.js:15285)
 at wrapListenerIn_markDirtyAndPreventDefault (core.js:15323)
 at HTMLButtonElement.<anonymous> (platform-browser.js:560)
 at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:406)
 at Object.onInvokeTask (core.js:28661)
 at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:405)
 at Zone.runTask (zone.js:178)
 at ZoneTask.invokeTask [as invoke] (zone.js:487)
```

and this is highlighted:

> formData.append("company_logo", this.files, this.files.name);

How do I get this sorted out?

Thanks

Comment: Try ```this.files?.name``` instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you submit the form without uploading an image, the property `this.files` does not have a value. The value is only set in the change handler of your file input (`onSelectFile`).

So in your form submit handler `onSubmit()` you should add the image data to your payload only if there is any data at all:

```js
// Before
formData.append("company_logo", this.files, this.files.name);

// After
if (this.files) {
  formData.append("company_logo", this.files, this.files.name);
}
```